# can pycuda parse float as unsigned char array as C++/CUDA does?

Tags: python, c++, casting, cuda

I'm trying to do base64 using pycuda for data transfer on network.
I need to convert float to byte or unsigned char and I did it just by cudamemcpy after I found memcpy works well on CPU.
I mean, I just do cuda mem copy some float values and take those values in the kernel by "unsigend char* " to treat it as byte array.

Also I saw my c++/cuda code works good too but the same code doesn't work in pycuda.

Partial code snap is as below;
C++/CUDA

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;

#define CHECK(call)                                                            \
{                                                                              \
    const cudaError_t error = call;                                            \
    if (error != cudaSuccess)                                                  \
    {                                                                          \
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s:%d, ", __FILE__, __LINE__);                 \
        fprintf(stderr, "code: %d, reason: %s\n", error,                       \
                cudaGetErrorString(error));                                    \
        exit(1);                                                               \
    }                                                                          \
}  
// grid 2D block 2D
__global__ void base64_encode(int N, unsigned char* in, unsigned char* out) //////////////// not float type, but uchar to treat it as byte array!!

{
    unsigned int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x; 
    if (idx < N){
        out[idx] = in[idx];
        printf("cuda thread %d : %02x \n",idx, in[idx]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%s Starting...\n", argv[0]);
 
    int dev = 0;
    cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
    CHECK(cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, dev));
    printf("Using Device %d: %s\n", dev, deviceProp.name);
    CHECK(cudaSetDevice(dev));
 
    int nx = 1 << 2;
    int ny = 1 << 2;

    int nxy = nx * ny;
    int nBytes = nxy * sizeof(float);
    printf("Matrix size: nx %d ny %d\n", nx, ny);
 
    float *h_A, *hostRef;
    unsigned char * gpuRef;
    h_A = (float *)malloc(nBytes); 
    hostRef = (float *)malloc(nBytes);
    gpuRef = (unsigned char *)malloc(nBytes);
    int size= (int)(nxy/ sizeof(float));

    unsigned char b[nxy];//sizeof(float)
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        h_A[i] = (float)(i & 0xFF);
        cout << h_A[i]  << ", " << endl;
    }
    memset(hostRef, 0, nBytes);   
    memcpy(b, &h_A, nxy);  
    memset(gpuRef, 0, nBytes);
    
    unsigned char *d_input, *d_output;
    CHECK(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_input, nBytes)); 
    CHECK(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_output, nBytes));
 
    CHECK(cudaMemcpy(d_input, h_A, nBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)); 
 
    int dimx = 4*4; 
    dim3 block(dimx, 1);
    dim3 grid((nxy + block.x - 1) / block.x );
 
    base64_encode<<<grid, block>>>(nxy, d_input, d_output);
    CHECK(cudaDeviceSynchronize());  
    CHECK(cudaGetLastError()); 
    CHECK(cudaMemcpy(gpuRef, d_output, nBytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
  
    for (int i = 0; i < nxy; i++) 
        printf("%02x, ",gpuRef[i]); 
 
    CHECK(cudaFree(d_input)); 
    CHECK(cudaFree(d_output));
 
    free(h_A); 
    free(hostRef);
    free(gpuRef);
 
    CHECK(cudaDeviceReset());

    return (0);
}
```

and the result looks good

```
0, 
1, 
2, 
3, 
cuda thread 0 : 00 
cuda thread 1 : 00 
cuda thread 2 : 00 
cuda thread 3 : 00 
cuda thread 4 : 00 
cuda thread 5 : 00 
cuda thread 6 : 80 
cuda thread 7 : 3f 
cuda thread 8 : 00 
cuda thread 9 : 00 
cuda thread 10 : 00 
cuda thread 11 : 40 
cuda thread 12 : 00 
cuda thread 13 : 00 
cuda thread 14 : 40 
cuda thread 15 : 40 
00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 80, 3f, 00, 00, 00, 40, 00, 00, 40, 40
```

PyCUDA code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as drv
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray

kernel = SourceModule("""
#include <stdio.h>  
using namespace std;

__global__ void base64_encode(int N, unsigned char* in, unsigned char* out){
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x; 
    if (idx < N){
        out[idx] = in[idx];
        printf("cuda thread %d : %02x \\n",idx, in[idx]);
    }
}
""")
def gpu_rgb2gray(): 
    floatValue = np.asarray(1.0).astype(np.float32)
    floatValue_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(floatValue.nbytes) 
    cuda.memcpy_htod(floatValue_gpu, floatValue)
    
    h_output = np.asarray(0.0).astype(np.float32)      
    d_output = cuda.mem_alloc(h_output.nbytes)
    cuda.memcpy_htod(d_output, h_output) 
    base64_encoder = kernel.get_function("base64_encode") 
    blockDim = (4, 1, 1)  
    gridDim = (1, 1, 1)  
    base64_encoder(4, floatValue_gpu, d_output, block=blockDim, grid=gridDim)
    
    h_output2 = np.array(d_output.get(), dtype=np.ubyte) 
    return 0#h_output
```

this code shows and error : TypeError: invalid type on parameter #0 (0-based)
Could I ask anybody help me please?

Answer (score 2):

First of all this import:

```
import pycuda.driver as drv
```

doesn't match the rest of your code. To match the rest of your code, that should be:

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda
```

On to your question.  The parameter that pycuda is complaining about is parameter 0 (ie. the first parameter) in this line:

```
base64_encoder(4, floatValue_gpu, d_output, block=blockDim, grid=gridDim)
               ^
```

That has nothing to do with the usage of `float` or any of the subjects you bring up in your question.  In your kernel definition, you are expecting a 32-bit integer:

```
__global__ void base64_encode(int N, ...
                              ^^^
```

but a bare constant like that in python is evidently something else.  You can fix this by modifying the call like this:

```
base64_encoder(np.int32(4), floatValue_gpu, d_output, block=blockDim, grid=gridDim)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When I make those two changes, and run your `gpu_rgb2gray()` function, I get reasonable-looking `printf` output from the kernel.

After making those changes, although you're not really using it in the code you have posted, the next problem you will run into is here:

```
h_output2 = np.array(d_output.get(), dtype=np.ubyte)
```

Your `d_output` is a `DeviceAllocation` [object](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/driver.html#pycuda.driver.DeviceAllocation), not a `GPUArray` [object](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/array.html), and so it doesn't have a `get` attribute/method.  To fix that with minimum changes, I would just reverse the methodology you used to populate that object:

```
h_output2 = np.empty(floatValue.nbytes, dtype=np.ubyte)
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(h_output2, d_output)
```

Here is a complete example:

```
$ cat t29.py
import numpy as np
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as cuda
from   pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray

kernel = SourceModule("""
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

__global__ void base64_encode(int N, unsigned char* in, unsigned char* out){
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (idx < N){
        out[idx] = in[idx];
        printf("cuda thread %d : %02x \\n",idx, in[idx]);
    }
}
""")
def gpu_rgb2gray():
    floatValue = np.asarray(1.0).astype(np.float32)
    floatValue_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(floatValue.nbytes)
    cuda.memcpy_htod(floatValue_gpu, floatValue)

    h_output = np.asarray(0.0).astype(np.float32)
    d_output = cuda.mem_alloc(h_output.nbytes)
    cuda.memcpy_htod(d_output, h_output)
    base64_encoder = kernel.get_function("base64_encode")
    blockDim = (4, 1, 1)
    gridDim = (1, 1, 1)
    base64_encoder(np.int32(4), floatValue_gpu, d_output, block=blockDim, grid=gridDim)
    h_output2 = np.empty(floatValue.nbytes, dtype=np.ubyte)
    cuda.memcpy_dtoh(h_output2, d_output)
    return h_output2

print(gpu_rgb2gray())

$ cuda-memcheck  python t29.py
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
cuda thread 0 : 00
cuda thread 1 : 00
cuda thread 2 : 80
cuda thread 3 : 3f
[  0   0 128  63]
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```